# Is there any way to see if a user is currently signed in on the Firebase website?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Currently, the Firebase website only shows the users that **signed in before** as shown in the image below but it does not tell me who is **signed in at this very moment**. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this. Best is if I could view a log of the sign in/sign out activity. This is mainly for a school project, so it would help if I had something visual to show that users are signing in and out. The signed in users are from an app which I developed.

[image]

I tried using events like so :

```
private fun signIn() {
    val intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
    window.setWindowAnimations(0)
/**
 * For firebase analytics
 */
val user = mAuth!!.currentUser
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)

val log = Bundle()
log.putString("user_name", user?.displayName)
log.putString("time", System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
mFirebaseAnalytics?.logEvent("login_event", log)
}
```

But the even does not show up:

[image]

Comment: do u use firebase realtime db or any db? you can make log there

Comment: I have not implemented a db as of yet, since Firebase can already track if a user has signed in before, I was just wondering it has the ability to show me if the user is still signed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user signs in with Firebase Authentication, their sign-in session is indefinite and only ends once they explicitly sign out, or if there is the need to require them to sign in again (e.g. if the password is changed). For the majority of users, they will have to sign in once, and can then continue using the app (restarting it) without having to sign in again.

For this reason the number of users who are signed in will likely be *much* higher than the number of users who are currently using the app. The Firebase console does not show the current number of active users.

Through analytics you can try to get an estimate for the number of active users. But the most accurate way to track the active users is by [building a so-called presence system on top of Firebase's realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence). This is essentially a supercharged version of what Shehroz suggests in their answer. It may be a bit tricky to implement if you've never done this before, so I highly recommend starting from/using the [sample in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample).

Comment: Yes, I now agree with this, do you by any chance know why the event does not show up on the event page ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm do this way in my app and i hope it will help you also So what i'm  doing is that i've defined chatStatus child in realtime database of firebase but under uuid of that user and from your android application you only have update this status every time user start application by doing something like this in your oncreate method of mainactivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  YourDatabaseReference.child("Chat Status").setValue(boolean/Date);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events and get an idea about this firebase analytical process. This will help you to do lots of analytical tasks based on logs. Below code segement also get from official web site.

```
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    .....
    // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
   .....

   //for your work
   Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
   params.putString("user_name", name); 
   params.putString("loggintime", logintimestamp);
   mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("loggin_event", params);
```

you can do this for all your logs. But if you only log your user sign in and sign out. you can simply use your database table to keep your user data logs.

Comment: I tried it, my code is updated in the post, however I cant seem to see the event. Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal i didn't get it. what is the error ?

Comment: I should be seeing a `login_event` under events in the image shown in the post, because I sent an event. However, it does not seem to be showing my event.